# Table of contents when there are no chapters/sections

Tags: table-of-contents

I am using "article" class to write a report. Instead of using conventional section and subsections, I have defined new commands which I want to use in table of contents.

```
\newcommand{\CentreHeading}[1]{\begin{center} \begin{large} \MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}} \end{large} \end{center} \vspace*{28pt} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
```

Now, instead of using section command, I want to use \CentreHeading command to define sections and their arguments to appear in the table of contents.

A minimal MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\newcommand{\CentreHeading}[1]{\begin{center} \begin{large} \MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}} \end{large} \end{center} \vspace*{28pt} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    
    \CentreHeading{First Section}
    Foo bar boo bar
    
    \CentreHeading{Second Section}
    Again foo bar  boo bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the `\addcontentsline` command, replace `chapter` by `section`. The article class has no chapters.

Comment: @gernot Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `article` class which knows nothing about chapters.

```
% tocentryprob.tex  SE 570050

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\newcommand{\CentreHeading}[1]{\begin{center} \begin{large}
  \MakeUppercase{\textbf{#1}} \end{large} \end{center} \vspace*{28pt}
  %%% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}  % not that but this
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    
    \CentreHeading{First Section}
    Foo bar boo bar
    
    \CentreHeading{Second Section}
    Again foo bar  boo bar
\end{document}
```

In the `\addcontentsline` change `chapter` to `section`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.